# How to create and add custom analyser in Elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch

i have a batch of "smartphones" products in my ES and I need to query them by using "smart phone" text. So I m looking into the compound word token filter. Specifically , I m planning to use a custom filter like this:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_all/_settings -d '
{
  "analysis" : {
    "analyzer":{
      "second":{
        "type":"custom",
        "tokenizer":"standard",
        "filter":["myFilter"]
      }
      "filter": {
        "myFilter" :{
             "type" : "dictionary_decompounder"
             "word_list": ["smart", "phone"]
             }
             }             
    }
}
}
'
```

Is this the correct approach ? Also I d like to ask you how can i create and add the custom analyser to ES? I looked into several links but couldn't figure out how to do it. I guess I m looking for the correct syntax. 
Thank you

EDIT

I m running 1.4.5 version.
and I verified that the custom analyser was added successfully:

```
{
  "test_index" : {
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "creation_date" : "1453761455612",
        "analysis" : {
          "filter" : {
            "myFilter" : {
              "type" : "dictionary_decompounder",
              "word_list" : [ "smart", "phone" ]
            }
          },
          "analyzer" : {
            "second" : {
              "type" : "custom",
              "filter" : [ "lowercase", "myFilter" ],
              "tokenizer" : "standard"
            }
          }
        },
        "number_of_shards" : "5",
        "number_of_replicas" : "1",
        "version" : {
          "created" : "1040599"
        },
        "uuid" : "xooKEdMBR260dnWYGN_ZQA"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach looks good, I would also consider adding [lowercase token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lowercase-tokenfilter.html), so that even *Smartphone* (notice Uppercase 'S') will be split into *smart* and *phone*.

Then You could create index with analyzer like this,

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/your_index -d '
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "second": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "myFilter"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "myFilter": {
          "type": "dictionary_decompounder",
          "word_list": [
            "smart",
            "phone"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "second"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
'
```

Here you are creating index named *your_index*, `custom analyzer` named *second* and applied that to *name* field.

You can check if the analyzer is working as expected with [analyze api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/indices-analyze.html) like this

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/your_index/_analyze' -d '
{
  "analyzer" : "second",
  "text" : "LG Android smartphone"
}'
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thnx a lot for you answer. Looks very analytic and precise. I will try it and let you know if it works.

Comment: Hi Chintan. I added the custom analyser. However when , I ran the analyser check it didnt split the "smartphone" into "smart" and "phone".
Any suggestions?

Comment: what version of ES you are using?

Comment: it s 1.4.5. In my initial question you can also see that the custom analyser wad indeed added. And this is part of the result of the analyser test:
"token" : "smartphone",
    "start_offset" : 50,
    "end_offset" : 60,
    "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
    "position" : 6
  } ]

Comment: since you are on ES 1.4 this should work `curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/your_index/_analyze?analyzer=second&pretty' -d 'text=LG android smartphone'` , this is the doc [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/indices-analyze.html)

Comment: Right it worked when trying this: curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/your_index/_analyze?analyzer=second&pretty' -d 'text=LG android smartphone'

But does it mean that I need to specify in each query that the "second" analyser should be used?

Comment: what do you mean by each query? what kind of query, search qurery?

Comment: Yes I mean search query. Cause the thing is that when i make a search using the word "smart" or "phone", documents including "smartphone" do not appear. However, when i try the analyse API with the sample text "LG android smartphone" then indeed the "smartphone" breaks into "smart" and "phone". So I m really confused on how to get this analyser working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101686/discussion-between-chintanshah25-and-panipsilos).